# Ошибка InputStream под Android

Tags: android, input

Добрый день. Читаю книгу "Android. Программирование для профессионалов. 2-е издание". Глава 23 HTTP и фоновые задачи. Есть там такой пример кода

```
public class FlickrFetchr {
    public byte[] getUrlBytes(String urlSpec) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlSpec);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            **--->ОШИБКА!!!!** InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                throw new IOException(connection.getResponseMessage() +
                ": with " +
                urlSpec);
            }
            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            out.close();
            return out.toByteArray();
        } finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    public String getUrlString(String urlSpec) throws IOException {
        return new String(getUrlBytes(urlSpec));
    }
}
```

Вот примерно описание класса:
Исходная версия `FlickrFetchr` будет состоять всего из двух методов: `getUrlBytes(String)` и `getUrlString(String)`. Метод `getUrlBytes(String)` получает низкоуровневые данные по URL и возвращает их в виде массива байтов. Метод `getUrlString(String)` преобразует результат из `getUrlBytes(String)` в `String`.

Вот что мне выдает листинг:

```
05-06 04:18:54.508 17186-17232/com.alexdplua.photogallery E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                        Process: com.alexdplua.photogallery, PID: 17186
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
                                                                            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
                                                                            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                                                                            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:190)
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
                                                                            at com.alexdplua.photogallery.FlickrFetchr.getUrlBytes(FlickrFetchr.java:18)
                                                                            at com.alexdplua.photogallery.FlickrFetchr.getUrlString(FlickrFetchr.java:39)
                                                                            at com.alexdplua.photogallery.PhotoGalleryFragmernt$FetchItemsTask.doInBackground(PhotoGalleryFragmernt.java:50)
                                                                            at com.alexdplua.photogallery.PhotoGalleryFragmernt$FetchItemsTask.doInBackground(PhotoGalleryFragmernt.java:45)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                                         Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
                                                                            at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
                                                                            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
                                                                            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
                                                                            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) 
                                                                            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) 
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29) 
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232) 
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124) 
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272) 
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211) 
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373) 
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323) 
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:190) 
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210) 
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25) 
                                                                            at com.alexdplua.photogallery.FlickrFetchr.getUrlBytes(FlickrFetchr.java:18) <---**АКТИВНАЯ ССЫЛКА НА ОШИБКУ В КОДЕ (ОШИБКА УКЗАНА В КОДЕ КЛАССА)**
                                                                            at com.alexdplua.photogallery.FlickrFetchr.getUrlString(FlickrFetchr.java:39) 
                                                                            at com.alexdplua.photogallery.PhotoGalleryFragmernt$FetchItemsTask.doInBackground(PhotoGalleryFragmernt.java:50) 
                                                                            at com.alexdplua.photogallery.PhotoGalleryFragmernt$FetchItemsTask.doInBackground(PhotoGalleryFragmernt.java:45) 
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                                         Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied
```

Я нашел ответ на этот вопрос на форуме книги, раздел этой главы http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=574&t=10588
Но к сожалению он мне не помог. В чем ошибка? Спасибо заранее!
P.S. если информации не достаточно, задавайте вопросы - отвечу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пропишите в манифесте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Указано в логах на это:

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing
> INTERNET permission?)
> ```

Comment: Спасибо! Оказывается не проследил, и разрешение не в тот блок поставил. Скажите где можно найти материал что бы хорошо разбираться в логах? А то я только примитивно excep-шины могу искать.